# Error in If statment in R

Tags: r, if-statement

below is the code. It seems I have not managed to define the vectors 'nobs', 'cor' correctly and the if statement is trying to asses an NA value.
Can someone point me my error? 
Thanks,
Tamir

```
corr<-function(directory, threshold=0){

allfiles<-list.files("specdata", full.names = TRUE)
NumOfFiles<-length(allfiles)

n<-1
id<-vector()
nobs<-vector()
cor<-vector()

for (i in NumOfFiles){
    data<-read.csv(allfiles[i])
    cleandata<-data[complete.cases(data),]
    id[n]=i
    nobs[n]<-sum(complete.cases(data))  #Number of completre cases
    n<-n+1


 if (nobs[n]>threshold){
     cor[n]<-cor(cleandata[sulfate],cleandata[nitrate])
     }
}

 return(cor)
```

}

Comment: Your code, as it stands, is error-ridden. Make it reproducible.

Comment: To aid you in the right direction: 1. you are not iterating over a vector. 2. you use to variables for indexing (n and i), and you increase n and then try to access data stored at that position. 3 you use the name of a base function (`cor`) as a variable name). 4. You are incorrectly accessing columns of your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code wasn't that far off. I changed the position of `n <- n+1`. In your example, it was incrementing too early in the function. When the function got down to `if(nobs[n]>threshold)` it was checking AFTER you did n+1, so it was always `NA`.

Secondly, I put quotes around the pollutant names.

```
corr<-function(directory, threshold=0){

allfiles<-list.files("specdata", full.names = TRUE, pattern="csv")
NumOfFiles<-length(allfiles)

n<-1
id<-vector()
nobs<-vector()
cor<-vector()

for (i in 1:NumOfFiles){
    data<-read.csv(allfiles[i])
    cleandata<-data[complete.cases(data),]
    id[n]=i
    nobs[n]<- sum(complete.cases(data))  #Number of completre cases

    if (nobs[n]>threshold){
      cor[n]<-cor(cleandata[,"sulfate"],cleandata[,"nitrate"])
      n<-n+1
      }

}

 return(cor)
}
```

We can test with:

```
summary(corr("specdata"))
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-1.00000 -0.05205  0.10840  0.13800  0.27890  1.00000 

cr <- corr("specdata", 150)
head(cr)
[1] -0.01895754 -0.14051254 -0.04389737 -0.06815956
[5] -0.12350667 -0.07588814
```

Which both match the desired output.

Comment: Thank you Pierre. It works better but not with the same results you have. Why are the objects 'id', 'nobs' and 'cor' are not vectors but integers?