# Nothing inside my if() statement works

Tags: r

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out why nothing inside my `if()` statement works. I'm getting from this just a single value, or no value at all, and I'm expecting a vector with multiple values from every time my condition is met.

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0, a = 0) {
  y <- vector()
  for(i in 332) {
    x <- read.csv(paste("D:\\", directory, "\\", formatC(i, width = 3, flag = "0"), ".csv", sep = ""))
    z <- x[complete.cases(x),]
    n <- cor(z$sulfate,z$nitrate)
    if(nrow(z) > threshold) {
      a <- a + 1
      y[a] <- n
    }
  }
  return(y)
}
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible data set.

Comment: check [Error in If statment in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053436/error-in-if-statment-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

A reproducible example would make this easier, but one problem is that your `for` loop is only running once. To see a simplified example

```
for (i in 332) {
  print(i)
}

## [1] 332
```

Try it this way, which will actually loop over all the values from 1 to 332.

```
for (i in seq_len(332)) {
  ## the rest of your code here
}
```

Or

```
for (i in 1:332) {
  ## the rest of your code here
}
```